# Find the limit of Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

Suppose that $f(x)$ is on continuously differentiable function, with bounded derivative, defined on $[0,1]$ such that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f(x)-\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f(x)=1
$$
The Fourier coefficients of f are defined by
$$
\hat{f}(n)=\int_0^1f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx.
$$
Prove that, as $n \to ±\infty$, we have:
$$
\hat{f}(n)=\frac{i}{2\pi n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: An integration by parts shows that $$\hat f(n)=\frac1{-2\pi i n}
+\frac1{2\pi in}\widehat{f'}(n).$$

Comment: I think the first part in your RHS is zero.

Comment: @Gatsby I don't think so. Work it out again. The function $f$ doesn't have period $1$...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks